# How to select Nth element in subgroup using data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Simple task: I need to extract (lets say) 1st and  2nd elements of subgroup.

```
DT <- data.table (X=c(1,2), Y=round(rnorm(5),1), key="X"); DT

       X     Y
1:     1  -0.4
2:     1   0.5
3:     1   1.2
4:     2   1.0
5:     2  -0.3
```

So, I need to get DT2, which would be

```
1:     1  -0.4
2:     1   0.5
3:     2   1.0
4:     2  -0.3
```

This does not work:

```
 DT2 <- DT[, .(first = .SD[1], second=.SD[2]), by=X]
```

What works?

Comment: `.SD` stands for subset of data.table, set of columns. What you wanted to assign to `first` and `second` are single columns. Just use `Y[1L]` and `Y[2L]` instead of `.SD`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would

```
DT[, .SD[1:2], by = X]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do a group by `head`

```
DT[,  head(.SD, 2), X]
```

---

Or extract the row index (`.I`) and subset

```
DT[DT[, .I[1:2], X]$V1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code also produces the same result. If ordering is important, setkey or order can be run beforehand.

```
DT <- data.table (X=c(1,2), Y=round(rnorm(5),1), key="X"); DT
   X    Y
1: 1  0.5
2: 1  1.4
3: 1  0.0
4: 2 -1.5
5: 2 -0.3

DT[,Y[1:2],.(X)]

   X   V1
1: 1  0.5
2: 1  1.4
3: 2 -1.5
4: 2 -0.3
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's a solution using tidyverse/dplyr. The first section uses tibble, which is an extension of the usual data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  x = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  y = c(-0.4, 0.5, 1.2, 1.0, -0.3)
)

df
# A tibble: 5 x 2
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  -0.4
2     1   0.5
3     1   1.2
4     2   1  
5     2  -0.3

df2 <-
  df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  slice(1:2) %>% 
  ungroup()

df2
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1  -0.4
2     1   0.5
3     2   1  
4     2  -0.3
```